# What's a good pattern for a single selection from a list of objects in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns

I have a list of instances of some class.  One instance of that class must be "selected" at all times.  Therefore, when the first instance is created, it must be set as selected, and if a selected instance is removed, another from that class must be set as selected.

```
apple = Fruit.new
apple.favorite        # true

pear = Fruit.new
pear.make_favorite!   
apple.favorite        # false
pear.favorite         # true

pear.destroy
apple.favorite        # true
```

I have encountered this scenario a few times while developing Rails apps and have always ended up with an unsatisfactory, bug-inducing pile of callbacks to try to cover all edge cases without causing infinite update loops.  Does anyone know a nice pattern for this?

Comment: Can you be more specific, I have no idea what you're talking about? Some code sample?

Comment: added some code to illustrate the problem :)

Comment: Aaaand, what may be use for that?

Comment: Basically, it's the equivalent of the radio button UI control... with similar breadth of applicability. Any suggestions on nice ways of implementing it?

Comment: strange In ruby  `new Fruit()` is working? it should be `Fruit.new`

Comment: you're right, I've been doing half javascript tonight.  Fixed!

Comment: Radio button ui control has a GROUP of controls and I belive state is help in this group. And this is again different because you can find all elements with gives attr in HTML and finding all instances of a class in ruby seems at least exotic to me.

Comment: Do you want this to work on database rows or instances in memory in a controller action? In a view?

Comment: @Matt I suppose database rows would be the closest -- I want any one of a set of objects (table rows) to always have a boolean flag set, while none of the others do.  In my example, the objects are fruits and the flag is "favorite", but it could be anything.  There could be zero or one or two or 5000 objects in the set, it doesn't matter:  one and always one of them (if possible) will have the flag set.

Comment: I think state pattern would be your choice. Since you only need to maintain one state at a time. While the first fruit object is created. The owner sets the fruit object(state).

Answer (score 0):

The Fruit class should have a static member of type Fruit and it should point to the favorite fruit

on testing .favorite, it should return self==favorite

on make_favorite, you should change it to point to self

on destroy you should check if self==favorite , if so, just make it to point to Fruit.all.first - If no fruit exists it will become null

If you are creating new fruit and the favorite is null, make it to point to the new fruit (self)

Is there any problem with this mechanism?

Comment: Well.... would that persist?  Since HTTP is stateless, the static Fruit.favorite would only be set for the lifecycle of each request, and "lost" between requests.  I think you need to set a flag on the favorite fruit and (this is the hard part) make sure that flag is not set on any others, without causing excessive cascading updates or loops.

Comment: Hi, you didn't mention the persistency, if so, I would have some table that holds my setting and will hold the ID of the favorite fruit and it will be read at the beginning and will be write back on every change. The flag option is also a possibility, but then you need to go over the whole table each time you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use just add a boolean to the Fruit class and set the instance to true if Fruit.last

Comment: What happens when you add another Fruit?

Comment: set every other fruit to false?

Comment: so the selected Fruit is always the last one created?  What if I want to set "banana" to be my favorite?  The favorite should only be updated if I delete "banana".